# Import random columns from spreadsheet into order in new spreadsheet

Tags: performance, import, spreadsheet

I'm trying to code a script that imports specific columns for a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet. However, currently i'm writing/reading every column separately, which takes quite a while. I do this because I don't need all the columns from the original sheet into the new sheet. I was wondering if my current script could be changed to get to a script where you once read the necessary columns and write them all together? I tried to search for the same but the different order of the columns and the need for specific columns makes it hard.

I hope someone could help me get to the answer.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

```
    function getPDdataupper() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SPR');

 var Num = Browser.inputBox("What URL are do you want to copy from?");
 var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.openById(Num);//put Address in here*****

var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("SPR");

 sheet.getRange(10,11,(sheet.getLastRow())-9,3).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(10,1,(sheet.getLastRow())-9,3).clearContent();

  //ADJUST ROW
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()-10;
  var lastrowcopiedsheet = sheetraw.getLastRow()-10;
  var diff = lastrowcopiedsheet - lastrow;

if(diff > 0){sheet.insertRowsAfter(11,diff);}
  if(diff < 0){sheet.deleteRows(20,(diff*-1)); }

  sheet.getRange(11,1,(sheet.getLastRow())-11,33).clearContent();

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(1,1,5,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(1,1,5,1).setValues(values);

 var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,3,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,2,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,38,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,2).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,3,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),2).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,43,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,6,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,44,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,5,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,6,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,7,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,54,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,2).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,8,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),2).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,58,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,10,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,14,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,19).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,14,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),19).setValues(values);

   var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,51,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,33,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,62,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,34,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);

  var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,4,sheetraw.getLastRow()-9,1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange(10,35,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),1).setValues(values);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sorted it myself now. For someone who is looking for the same thing, please see the code below. If anyone else thinks of something better please feel free to amend.

```
function getPDdataupper() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SPR');

 var folder= DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderID');
 var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next());
 //var ssraw = SpreadsheetApp.open(Num); 
 }
    sheet.getRange(11,1,(sheet.getLastRow())-10,53).clearContent();
var sheetraw = ssraw.getSheetByName("SPR");

 sheet.getRange(10,11,(sheet.getLastRow())-9,3).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(10,1,(sheet.getLastRow())-9,3).clearContent();

  //ADJUST ROW
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow()-10;
  var lastrowcopiedsheet = sheetraw.getLastRow()-10;
  var diff = lastrowcopiedsheet - lastrow;

if(diff > 0){sheet.insertRowsAfter(11,diff);}
  if(diff < 0){sheet.deleteRows(20,(diff*-1)); }


  //var values = sheetraw.getRange(10,("C10:C,AL10:AM,AQ10:AR,F10:F,BB10:BC,BF10:BF"),(sheetraw.getLastRow()-9),53).getValues();
  //sheet.getRange(10,2,(sheet.getLastRow()-9),(sheet.getLastColumn()-1)).setValues(values);

        var data = sheetraw.getDataRange().getValues();{
        var target = new Array();
        for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
            target.push( [[data[n][2]], [data[n][37]], [data[n][38]], [data[n][43]], [data[n][42]], [data[n][5]], [data[n][53]], [data[n][54]], [data[n][57]]] );

           }

        sheet.getRange(1,2,target.length,target[0].length).setValues(target);

}
```